# How can I present a library as a custom view?

Tags: sharepoint, list, view, custom-controls

I have a Sharepoint library that is currently rendering as the usual folder and document items table list view.

I would like to use present the same information as a grid of folder and document icons with some nice jQuery hover animations to show tooltips on the item the icon represents.

I suppose what I am really trying to find out is how to add a new library view that allows me to specify the markup rendered per item. I could write a new webpart to query the list and use an ASP:Repeater but I don't want to have to specify a webpart property each page to tell the webpart where it should open the list from.

Comment: Is this for one library or are you intending to use this for a default view on a definition or template to be reused?

Comment: @SHug, I'm hoping to have this view as the default view for all curernt currently Page List table views. Ideally, I'd still like to be able to select the traditional view if required from the ribbon.

Answer (score 1):

You can use List View Web Part with custom XSLT.